# javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException when using @TestPropertySource

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to use **@TestPropertySource** to override some properties for a specific test:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties=['bbCheckout.connectTimeout=500'])
```

This is used in a Configuration class:

```
    @Bean
@Primary
public ChargeTransactionClient wireMockChargeTransactionClient() {
    return new JacksonFeignBuilder<ChargeTransactionClient>()
            .options(new Request.Options(bbCheckoutConnectTimeout, bbCheckoutReadTimeout))
            .target(ChargeTransactionClient.class,
                    bbCheckoutProtocol + "://" + bbCheckoutHost + ":" + bbCheckoutPort + "/");
}
```

When I run the test by itself everything works as expected. But if I run the test as part of all the other component tests in my project the test fails with:

> com.blackbaud.transactor.resources.TransactionTimedoutResourceSpec > A timedout transaction should be published to the timedout transactions service bus FAILED
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>
> ```
>    Caused by:
>    org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentManager@69d2050e] with key 'environmentManager'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
>
>        Caused by:
>         javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.cloud.context.environment:name=environmentManager,type=EnvironmentManager
> ```

I've tried adding **@DirtiesContext** to the test, **@EnableMBeanRegistration(registration=RegistrationPolicy.REPLACE_IF_EXISTS)** and **@EnableMBeanExport(defaultDomain="differentDomains")** in the Configuration class and the test class.